# Provisioning Profiles for Production Deleted

Tags: ios, iosdeployment

Hello I have created two provisioning profiles for my app, one production and the other development. After created both I downloaded them and used them accordingly to deploy deploy the application in the AppStore. 
Now I went to see in the https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/ to see all the profiles created and I only see the one for development...the distribution one is gone...I have the file in my mac, and I can use it to deploy the app again but what are the issues with this situation that I might be facing...should I create another one and deploy next updates with the one provisioning profile for production? 
Thanks!

Comment: I guess if you CAN deploy with old you won't face any problems, if there is an error you'll get it while deploying... I also don't think that new provision profile will make problems... If it was the certificate I was more careful though

Comment: thanks @Yitschak that's why I wanted to be sure, since I don't have any issues while deploying and so far using the provisioning file that I have in my laptop I'm able to do the regular deployment process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you CAN deploy with old you won't face any problems, if there is an error you'll get it while deploying... I also don't think that new provision profile will make problems... If it was the certificate I was more careful though